# Q_PROPERTY compilation error

Tags: javascript, qt, qt5.5, qt5.6

**My work Environment : Qt 5.8 MSVC2015 64bit, Windows 7 64 bit.**

I am calling  C++ method from java script successfully. 
But failed to get return value of C++ method in JavaScript. 
So I try to use `Q_PROPERTY` to get return value of C++ method in JavaScript code.

```
class ExportedObject : public QObject
{   
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QString myprop MEMBER m_buffer READ GetValue WRITE GetTile)

public:
    Q_INVOKABLE void GetTile(int row, int col, int level);
    Q_INVOKABLE QString GetValue();
    QString m_buffer;
```

It gives me below error :

**error: C2660: 'ExportedObject::GetTile': function does not take 1 arguments**

JavaScript Code :

```
var image =  window.interface.GetTile( row , col ,level);
```

Any clue what I am missing in `Q_PROPERTY` ?

Is their better option to get C++ return value in JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

I just found simple solution for it, No need of Q_PROPERTY  :

```
window.interface.GetTile( row , col ,level, function(returnValue) {
    alert(returnValue);
});
```